# Using Beautiful Soup on multiple URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have searched through a lot of similar questions, but I'm unable to resolve the issue with the code below.

I am trying to scrape the same information from 2 separate URLs.

There is no issue when I scrape 1 URL (code 1). I then attempt to for loop through multiple URLs (code 2) and it throws this error:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Is it a case that the line where the error is returned (highlighted below) should not be included within the For Loop? (I have tried this unsuccessfully)

Could someone please educate me in why this is not working (my guess would be that the structure is wrong in someway - but I've been unable to adjust it correctly), or if this is infact not the optimal method at all

First code:

```
import csv 
import pandas as pd  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq 
import numpy as np
import re


url = "https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/pepsi-indian-premier-league-2014-695871/chennai-super-kings-vs-royal-challengers-bangalore-42nd-match-734013/full-scorecard"

url_contents = ureq(url) #opening the URL
soup = soup(url_contents,"html.parser") #parse the 
batsmen = soup.find_all("table", { "class":["table batsman"]})
bowlers = soup.find_all("table", { "class":["table bowler"]})

for batsman in batsmen[0]:
    with open('testcsv3.csv', 'a',newline='') as csvfile:
        f = csv.writer(csvfile)
        print (batsmen)
    
        for x in batsman:
            rows = batsman.find_all('tr')[:-2] #find all tr tag(rows)
        for tr in rows:
            data=[]
            cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags(columns)
            for td in cols:
                data.append(td.text.strip())
            f.writerow(data)
            print(data)


for bowler in bowlers[1]:
    with open('testcsv3.csv', 'a',newline='') as csvfile:
        f = csv.writer(csvfile)
        print (bowlers)
    
        for x in bowler:
            rows = bowler.find_all('tr') #find all tr tag(rows)
        for tr in rows:
            data=[]
            cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags(columns)
            for td in cols:
                data.append(td.text.strip())
            f.writerow(data)
            print(data)
```

Second code:

```
import csv # to do operations on CSV
import pandas as pd  # file operations
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  #Scraping tool
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq # For requesting data from link
import numpy as np
import re

urls = ["https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/pepsi-indian-premier-league-2014-695871/chennai-super-kings-vs-royal-challengers-bangalore-42nd-match-734013/full-scorecard",
        "https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/pepsi-indian-premier-league-2014-695871/chennai-super-kings-vs-kolkata-knight-riders-21st-match-733971/full-scorecard"]

for url in urls:
    url_contents = ureq(url) #opening the URL
    soup = soup(url_contents,"html.parser") #parse the 
    **batsmen = soup.find_all("table", { "class":["table batsman"]})** #error here
    bowlers = soup.find_all("table", { "class":["table bowler"]})

for batsman in batsmen[0]:
    with open('testcsv3.csv', 'a',newline='') as csvfile:
        f = csv.writer(csvfile)
        print (batsmen)
    
        for x in batsman:
            rows = batsman.find_all('tr')[:-2] #find all tr tag(rows)
        for tr in rows:
            data=[]
            cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags(columns)
            for td in cols:
                data.append(td.text.strip())
            f.writerow(data)
            print(data)


for bowler in bowlers[1]:
    with open('testcsv3.csv', 'a',newline='') as csvfile:
        f = csv.writer(csvfile)
        print (bowlers)
    
        for x in bowler:
            rows = bowler.find_all('tr') #find all tr tag(rows)
        for tr in rows:
            data=[]
            cols = tr.find_all('td') #find all td tags(columns)
            for td in cols:
                data.append(td.text.strip())
            f.writerow(data)
            print(data)
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory it says their is no findall method in your result set which is true. Tag have find and findall method

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Noted regarding your comments on the error message. Thank you for your answer below as well; it clarified what the issue was as well as rectified the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you use the same name `soup` for class/function `soup(...)` and for result `soup = ...` - and you run it in loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

for url in urls:

    soup = soup(...)
```

In first loop all work correctly but class/function `soup()` is replaces by result `soup = ...` and in next loop it tries to use result `soup` as a class/function - and this makes problem.

In first code you run `soup = soup()` only once so it makes no problem.

If you use different names - ie. `BeautifoulSoup` instead of `soup` - then it will work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

for url in urls:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(...)
```

---

**BTW:**

In second code you have wrong indentations - you should run `for batsman in ...` and `for bowler in ...` inside `for url in urls:` but you run it outside (after exiting from loop `for url in urls:`) and this will give you results only for last `url`

Answer (score 1):

You can use request lib and try this

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/pepsi-indian-premier-league-2014-695871/chennai-super-kings-vs-royal-challengers-bangalore-42nd-match-734013/full-scorecard",
        "https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/pepsi-indian-premier-league-2014-695871/chennai-super-kings-vs-kolkata-knight-riders-21st-match-733971/full-scorecard"]

for url in urls:
  otp = req.get(url)
  if otp.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(otp.text,'lxml')
    batsmen = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table batsman'})
    bowlers = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table bowler'})
    for bat in batsmen:
      print(bat.find_all('td')) # here you can use find/find_all method
    for bowl in bowlers:
      print(bowl.find_all('td')) # here you can use find/find_all method
```